# Automating Priority-Web-SDK file upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, priority-web-sdk

I would like to create a command line (or other automated) method for uploading files to priority using the Web-SDK.  The best solution I have right now seems to be a simple webform activated by a python script.

Are there tools/examples for using Javascript and a file picker without opening the browser?  Are there Priority-Web-SDK ports to other environments? C#, Python, etc?

Any other suggestions also welcome.

**UPDATE June 14, 2020:**
I was able to complete the task for this client using a combination of Javascript, Python and C#.  A tangled mess indeed, but files were uploaded.  I am now revisiting the task and looking for cleaner solutions.

I found a working and usable Node module to compact the program into an executable to make it a viable option for deployment.

So the question becomes more focused => creating the input for uploadDataUrl() or uploadFile() without a browser form.

Answer (score 0):

You run node locally and use priority SDK.

*As long as you work in an environment that is capable to render JS.
You can send files through the function `uploadFile`. 
The data inside the **file object need to be written as 64 base file**.

Comment: It needs to run on a clients machine.  It feel like overkill installing node for a small script.  Is there a way to install node and my script bundled into a single executable?

Answer (score 0):

This nodejs script will upload a file to Priority. Make sure that `fetch-base64` is npm installed:

```
"use strict";

const priority = require('priority-web-sdk');
const fetch = require('fetch-base64');

const configuration = {...};

async function uploadFile(formName, zoomVal, filepath, filename) {
  try {
    await priority.login(configuration);
    let form = await priority.formStartEx(formName, null, null, null, 1, {zoomValue: zoomVal});
    await form.startSubForm("EXTFILES", null ,null);
    let data = await fetch.local(filepath + '/' + filename);
    let f = await form.uploadDataUrl(data[0], filename.match(/\..+$/i)[0], () => {});
    await form.fieldUpdate("EXTFILENAME", f.file); // Path
    await form.fieldUpdate("EXTFILEDES", filename);  // Name
    await form.saveRow(0);
  } catch(err) {
      console.log('Something bad happened:');
      console.dir(err);
  }
}

uploadFile('AINVOICES', 'T9679', 'C:/my/path', 'a.pdf');
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I was wondering if you could help me with this code.  I am struggling to understand how to format the inputs for uploadDataUrl() and am most of the time not getting any error using callbacks or promises.  Does this code still work for you?